# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\...\GuestbookPHP.php on line 43

Tags: php

I couldnt figure out why I am getting this error in my code. Can anyone help me figure this out please?

Just to let you know, my line 43 is

> INSERT INTO commentList

```
    <?php

$dbServer='localhost';
$dbUser='root';
$dbPass='password';
$dbName='Guestbook';

mysql_connect("$dbServer", "$dbUser", "$dbPass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$dbName") or die(mysql_error());


mysql_query("CREATE TABLE commentLlist(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
      PRIMARY KEY(id),
        name VARCHAR(30), 
        comment VARCHAR(160))")
    or die(mysql_error());  


  // Retrieving data from the url
  $name = $_GET['name'];
  $comment = $_GET['comment'];


  if ( $name != null && $comment != null ) {
        INSERT INTO commentList
        VALUES("$name", "$comment");

  } else if ($name == null) {
        INSERT INTO commentList 
        VALUES("Anonymous", "$comment");

  } else if ($comment == null) {
          INSERT INTO commentList 
          VALUES("$name", " has nothing to say!");



    $display_string = "<li>";
    $display_string .= "$name";
    $display_string .= " says";
    $display_string .= "$comment";
    $display_string .= "<li>";


    echo $display_string;


?>
```

Comment: What is the content of the comment and name field when you get the error? Does it happen all the time, or only on certain comments? Is this a branded blog software, or a home-brew?

Comment: As a side note, your table is called commentLlist, not commentList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is wrong :

```
if ( $name != null && $comment != null ) {
    INSERT INTO commentList
    VALUES("$name", "$comment");
```

What you want to do is to send this query to mysql right?

So you need to use `mysql_query` function. So you should write something like this :

```
if ( $name != null && $comment != null ) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO commentList VALUES('".$name."', '".$comment."')");
}
```

Also there's a missing curly brace after your last else statement.

---

Also, putting user input directly into your query is a realy bad idea. You should escape your parameters using `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

```
if ( $name != null && $comment != null ) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO commentList 
        VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($comment)."')");
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for pointing out all the errors! It works perfectly fine now